# Images are not loading in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

We are not able to load images in the frontend website. We have used `<img src="{{ asset('assets/shop/img/ic-logo-gold.svg') }}" alt="logo" />` to display images.

Our images are located in `app\themes\OneTheme\SyliusShopBundle\public\img` and we have executed `bin/console  sylius:theme:assets:install --symlink` for assets install.

Anything missing here?

Edit:

In browser, generated image path `<img src="/assets/shop/img/ic-cart.svg">` and in web `assets` folder is not created.

Comment: I am not a user of Sylius, but can you check in the web folder what is generated by your command (assets:install).
I know that the symfony command creates a "bundles" folder, which I don't see in your path...
After that, please check in the browser in the dom what does generate in the src, just to be sure...

Comment: @Constantin: Edited

Comment: You have to find your image somewhere in the "web" folder. 
If it isn't in there you will never be able to show it.
Can you try to find the image in the web folder and use this path (without web) for the asset() ?

Comment: I guess you will have to run symfony asset:install first as I can read this in the doc of Sylius `Theme assets are installed by running the sylius:theme:assets:install command, which is supplementary for and should be used after assets:install.`

Answer (score 0):

The asset path should be: bundles/syliusshop/
as you have put under "SyliusShopBundle"

Try change to below and see that would work:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/syliusshop/img/ic-logo-gold.svg') }}" alt="logo" />
```